# Italy (Schengen) visa application different firstnames question

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, italy

I have an upcoming appointment for Italy tourist visa at the consulate in San Francisco. My official first name is **xyzkumar patel**. However, my support documents such as employment letter and bank statements have my name listed as **xyz patel**.

Will this be a problem? Should I bring any affidavit to show that I am the same person?

Comment: I do not know how Italy consulate will handle this, but I expect most Italian will use a different name for banks and other documents (and not the official name). The official name may include many names we normally never use but on few official documents.